# Detecting tap events in quick succession

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have page which shows either one of a number of images or a button. On clicking the button I hide it and display the next image in the list. Tapping the image makes it disappear and shows the button again.

When clicking the button multiple times in quick succession the displayed image doesn't respond to being tapped. I guess it is due to UI thread blocking but I tried it with worker thread and still is not working.

```
public void ShowNextImage()
    {

image_new.Source = getCurrentBitmap();
 workerThread.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        workerThread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        workerThread.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        workerThread.RunWorkerCompleted += new      RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
 workerThread.RunWorkerAsync();
  }
  void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {

                transition.Begin();
                transition.Completed += delegate
                {
                    transition.Stop();
                };


        });


    }
    void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,
                           RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            // Happens on the UI thread so its ok
            MessageBox.Show("Error occurred...");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you improve that title so its a question?

Comment: What event are you subscribing to on the image?

Comment: Can you please show some code which demonstrates what you're doing and allows us to recreate the issue.

Comment: @Stuart:Sorry i am new to this stackoverflow Anyway thanx for this.

Comment: @Richard I want to apply simple tap event lki double_Tap Single_tap etc to zoom the image or hide the button respectively

Comment: @Stuart:Yeah i'm sharing the code for your reference

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you in install the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291) from Codeplex and use the `GestureListener`.  This lets you detect many things not just `Tap` and `DoubleTap`, it will also support pinch sizing and dragging.

Make sure in open the source code in VS2010 and take a look at the `GestureSample.xaml` you could probably just lift most of that into your app.

Comment: I'm using the GestureListener but the problem is that the transition effects is going on on the images thats why images are not taking the any event so i want to know how to stop one transition if another transtion started on the image.

Answer (score 0):

My *guess* is that you're delegate code is causing problems:

```
  transition.Completed += delegate
            {
                transition.Stop();
            };
```

My guess is that among all the thread context switches the Completed event is getting fired while you are just about starting the next image transition.

There are a few things you could try to help with this:

- definitely only subscribe to completed once per transition
- try using separate transition instances for each actual transition
- try protecting the button so that it can't be pressed while the transition is occurring
- try letting the transition stop on its own (they don't have to repeat?)
- try reorganising the transition logic so that its not quite so multithreaded (not sure what else is going on in the app - I understand this may not be entirely possible if you've got lots of other things going on)
- try using VisualStateManager state changes instead of these manually crafted transitions

Don't try them all together :)

Of course, my guess might be wrong... it might be something else...

Comment: Just confusing you even more now - have added a second possible answer - sorry!

Comment: Is their any sample code link for the VisualStateManager is available

Comment: Actually i'm new on this platform and i'm just trying to solve a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Reading this again... another possibility is that something is being drawn over the top of the button and that this is capturing the touch events.

One basic suggestion is:

- get rid of the workerthread code - go back to just UI code
- put some simple Debug.WriteLine code in the Button_Click handler

Using this will tell you whether the Button is still responding to the click events or whether something more complicated has occurred. My experience is that normally the Button's keep on working at the click level now matter how many times you hit them - so something else is going wrong either in the click logic itself or in something else being shown over the top of the button, preventing it from being clicked.

Comment: Yes button clicking is working and it is still changing the image perfectly.But when i tap or double tap on the image it is not working because the transition is going on the image